# How to plot a wordCloud for essay text from a confusion matrix false positive rate count?

Tags: word-embeddings, data-science-model, confusion-matrix

I have an essay of text(BOW) and I have modelled it using let's say any model and plotted the confusion matrix and that I have got FPR, I need to plot a word cloud which shows the words due to which the FPR has occurred.

Comment: What do you mean by FPR

Comment: @Peter False positive rate

Comment: Let me try to correct his question if I am not wrong.
@Prasoon Singh, wants to see high weightage keywords from training dataset, those are False Positive.